# AWS Glue - Workflow - Running two jobs in a row issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I am with a issue when I run my workflow that has two jobs and the first one is the source for the second one. The second one is not reading all data from the first one and if I run the second job again than it will get the missing data. Has someone faced it before?

Looks like my first job didn't finish its writing and my second job is already trying to read it. Below I give more details.

I got a workflow which reads a bucket and does only a initial transformation from JSON to Parquet format. So, it crawls this bucket and refreshes its schema. This schema is available in a database called DB_RAW. The second job, within the same workflow, is responsible to read this table with raw data and makes some transformation which will be also stored into a bucket and crawled. This second table would be the data model where the data analysts will build their report using a data visualisation tool.
I am using Job Bookmark to manage when the new files should be ingested.

[image]

First job code

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue.transforms import Relationalize, ResolveChoice
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name, from_unixtime, unix_timestamp, year, col, when, struct
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import boto3

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME', 'Environment'])
env = args["Environment"]
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session.builder.appName('Raw - Data Pipeline').getOrCreate()
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

#get data from s3
connection_options = {"paths": [ "s3://bucket/landing/consolidated/"]}
dyf_vpm_consolidated_raw = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(connection_type="s3", connection_options=connection_options, format="json", format_options={"multiline":"true"}, transformation_ctx="dyf_vpm_consolidated_raw") 

#convert dynamic frame to data frame and add the required columns
df_vpm_consolidated_raw = dyf_vpm_consolidated_raw.toDF()
df_vpm_consolidated_raw = df_vpm_consolidated_raw.withColumn("filename", input_file_name()) 
df_vpm_consolidated_raw = df_vpm_consolidated_raw.withColumn("date", from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("filename").substr(-14,8), "yyyyMMdd")))
df_vpm_consolidated_raw = df_vpm_consolidated_raw.withColumn("year", year(df_vpm_consolidated_raw["date"])) 
df_vpm_consolidated_raw = df_vpm_consolidated_raw.withColumn("type", when(col("filename").contains("28days"), "28").otherwise("7")) 

#convert the data frame to dynamic frame
dyf_vpm_consolidated_staging = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df_vpm_consolidated_raw, glueContext, "dyf_vpm_consolidated_staging")

#rationalise the dynamic frame to flatten the columns 
dyf_vpm_consolidated_rationalised_collection = Relationalize.apply(frame = dyf_vpm_consolidated_staging, staging_path = "s3://bucket/scripts/temporary-glue-files/", name = "root", transformation_ctx = "dyf_vpm_consolidated_rationalised_collection")
dyf_vpm_consolidated_staging = dyf_vpm_consolidated_rationalised_collection.select("root")

#convert to df again and renaming the column
df_vpm_consolidated_staging = dyf_vpm_consolidated_staging.toDF()
df_vpm_consolidated_staging = df_vpm_consolidated_staging.withColumnRenamed("columx", "columx")
df_vpm_consolidated_staging = df_vpm_consolidated_staging.withColumnRenamed("columx", "columx")
df_vpm_consolidated_staging = df_vpm_consolidated_staging.withColumnRenamed("columx", "columx")
df_vpm_consolidated_staging = df_vpm_consolidated_staging.withColumnRenamed("columx", "columx")
df_vpm_consolidated_staging = df_vpm_consolidated_staging.withColumnRenamed("columx", "columx")
df_vpm_consolidated_staging = df_vpm_consolidated_staging.withColumnRenamed("columx", "columx")
df_vpm_consolidated_staging = df_vpm_consolidated_staging.withColumnRenamed("columx", "columx")
df_vpm_consolidated_staging = df_vpm_consolidated_staging.withColumnRenamed("columx", "columx")
df_vpm_consolidated_staging = df_vpm_consolidated_staging.withColumnRenamed("columx", "columx")
df_vpm_consolidated_staging = df_vpm_consolidated_staging.withColumnRenamed("columx", "columx")
df_vpm_consolidated_staging = df_vpm_consolidated_staging.withColumnRenamed("columx", "columx")
df_vpm_consolidated_staging = df_vpm_consolidated_staging.withColumnRenamed("columx", "columx")
df_vpm_consolidated_staging = df_vpm_consolidated_staging.withColumnRenamed("columx", "columx")

#convert to final dynamic frame
dyf_vpm_consolidated_final = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df_vpm_consolidated_staging, glueContext, "dyf_vpm_consolidated_final")

#write the file
connection_options = {"path": "s3://bucket/raw/consolidated/", "partitionKeys": ["year", "type"]}
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame=dyf_vpm_consolidated_final, connection_type="s3", connection_options=connection_options, format="parquet")

job.commit()
```

Code Second Job

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue.transforms import Relationalize, ResolveChoice
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id, regexp_replace, col, lit, explode, array, struct, regexp_replace, substring, when
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType
import boto3

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME", "Environment"])
env = args["Environment"]
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session.builder.appName("Transform - Data Pipeline").getOrCreate()
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)


dyf_vpm_consolidated_analytics = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "db_insights_raw", table_name = "tb_consolidated", transformation_ctx = "dyf_vpm_consolidated_analytics")
#dyf_vpm_consolidated_analytics = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_catalog(database = "db_insights_raw", table_name = "tb_consolidated", transformation_ctx = "dyf_vpm_consolidated_analytics")
#convert dynamic frame to data frame
df_vpm_consolidated_raw = dyf_vpm_consolidated_analytics.toDF()
print("Count row table 0:" + str(df_vpm_consolidated_raw.count())) 

#prepare data to create the Dimensions
#df_vpm_consolidated_raw = df_vpm_consolidated_raw.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
df_vpm_consolidated_raw = df_vpm_consolidated_raw.withColumn("episodeName", regexp_replace("episodeName", ",", ""))
df_vpm_consolidated_raw = df_vpm_consolidated_raw.withColumn("episodeName", regexp_replace("episodeName", "\n", " "))
df_vpm_consolidated_raw = df_vpm_consolidated_raw.withColumn("genre", regexp_replace("genre", ",", ""))
df_vpm_consolidated_raw = df_vpm_consolidated_raw.withColumn("seriesName", regexp_replace("seriesName", ",", ""))
df_vpm_consolidated_raw = df_vpm_consolidated_raw.withColumn("programName", regexp_replace("programName", ",", ""))
df_vpm_consolidated_raw = df_vpm_consolidated_raw.withColumn("classification", regexp_replace("classification", ",", ""))
df_vpm_consolidated_raw = df_vpm_consolidated_raw.withColumn("minutesViewed", (col("millisecondsViewed") / 60000).cast(DoubleType()))

connection_options = {"path": "s3://bucket/analytics/consolidated/vpm/", "partitionKeys": ["year", "type"]}
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame=dyf_vpm_consolidated, connection_type="s3", connection_options=connection_options, format="parquet")

job.commit()
```

Comment: What happens when you run these two jobs separately one after another with out workflow?

Comment: Same thing. I just tried to create to workflow on for the first job and another one for the second job and same issue.

Comment: It was funny because if I took some time and i run the second job again it gets the missing files and completes my dataset.

Comment: On what crawler event you are calling the job 2 ? Are you waiting for crawler to finish or you are starting job 2 based on job 1 events? I see the job 1 is creating a partitioned table and your crawler needs to be finished before you start job2 so that all partitions are available to be loaded into job2.

Comment: As soon as I finish the crawler for the process Raw I got a trigger that is watching this crawler, the if it succeed I would trigger the second job.

Comment: As soon as the crawler finishes can you run a query in athena to see if the table has all records that you wanted ? Also check the time of the partitions updated in raw table https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glue/get-partitions.html and the time when actual execution for second job started?

Comment: Yep, I just did it. So when my first jobs finishes (raw data) I got arounf 680.000 records, the my process moves on and when it gets to the second one it has 450. It has partitions.